# Verification of induction proof for handshake lemma

Tags: graph-theory, induction, solution-verification

I did the following proof which seems correct to me but does not match the approach of the answer provided by my professor, and seems pretty  different from the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782216/is-my-induction-proof-of-the-handshake-lemma-correct-graph-theory) in terms of notation and style. If I could get a verification that I'm correctly using induction on the number of edges of a graph, that would be great. Any tips on the clarity of my mathematical writing are also welcome. Thanks!

**Question:** prove the handshake lemma for simple graphs using induction on the number of edges. $$G=(V,E), \; \sum_{u\in V} \deg(u)=2|E|$$
**Proof:**

*Base Case:*
 $|E|=1$. $\sum_{u\in V} \deg(u) = 2|E| = 2(1) =2$.

*Inductive Step:* Assume that all graphs w/ $|E| = n\geq 1, \: n \in \mathbb{N}$, fufill equality.

Let $G=(V,E)$ w/ $|E| = n+1$. Remove any edge from $G$, making $G' = (V, E')$, where now $|E'|=n$. Therefore, inductive assumption applies and the identity holds. $$\sum_{u\in V} \deg(u) = 2|E|$$
Now, add the removed edge back to $G'$. Because this edge is indecent on two vertices, we add two to the previous sum.

\begin{align}
\sum_{u\in V} \deg(u) +2 &= 2|E| + 2 \tag{by Inductive Assumption}\\
&=2(n) + 2\\
&=2(n+1)
\end{align}
As required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I wouldn't say your proof is substantially different to the linked one; they're both correct.

The only advice I'd give is about your base case. Primarily, I think it needs some words. It's not clear from the one line of equalities, why a graph with one edge must have $2$ as the sum of its vertices' degrees. You can explain more clearly that given $m$ vertices, having one edge between them means that two of the vertices have degree $1$, and the rest have degree $0$, making the sum of the degrees $2$.

Or, even simpler and more generally, start with $n = 0$. If there are no edges in a graph, then the degree of every vertex is $0$, so the sum of degrees is also $0$.

Comment: On a second look, the linked question is the same proof. Sorry! I think I got tripped up by the difference in notation used and writing style. Also, thanks for the tips!